# polymer iron-ajax : How to Bind data from input element to iron-ajax's body attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer

I recently have problems binding data from input element to iron-ajax's "body" attribute.
When I used core-ajax on polymer 0.5, I can easily bind values like this:

```
<core-ajax
           id="ajax"
           method="POST" 
           contentType="application/json"
           url="{{url}}"   
           body='{"username":"{{username}}", "password":"{{password}}"}'
           handleAs="json"
           on-core-response="{{responseHandler}}">
</core-ajax>
```

Now I tried the same thing with iron-ajax. But it sends literally "{{username}}" and "{{password}}" instead of their values. Here is the code:

```
<iron-ajax
           id="ajax"
           method="POST" 
           contentType="application/json"
           url="{{url}}"   
           body='{"username":"{{username}}", "password":"{{password}}"}'
           handle-as="json"
           on-response="responseHandler">
</iron-ajax>
```

How to make it work? Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a computed property for the ajax body. Like so

```
properties: {
    ...
    ajaxBody: {
        type: String,
        computed: 'processBody(username, password)'
    }
},
processBody: function(username, password) {
    return JSON.stringify({username: username, password:password});
}
```

And then adding it on iron-ajax

```
<iron-ajax ... body="{{ajaxBody}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Comment: This also works for computing the `params` property. However in this case you want to return an `Object` instead of a string.

Comment: Nice answer, using the property instead of a function directly allow the call to be performed again if a parameter changes... might not be useful here but in some other cases it is.

Comment: This causes `processBody` to be called on every single change in the input-fields, rather than computed on request serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Computed Bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed)

Your code would look something like this:

```
<iron-ajax
       ...
       body="{{getAjaxBody(username, password}}}"
       >
</iron-ajax>
<script>
Polymer({
  .....
  getAjaxBody: function(username, password) {
    return JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Work with the nez Polymer but syntax as changed to `body="[[getAjaxBody(username, password)]]"`