# iron-ajax to only make request if url parameter exists

Tags: ajax, html, polymer

This `iron-ajax` should make a request only if an url-parameter named itemId exists. And that parameter should also be added to the request:

```
<iron-ajax auto="false" 
    url="/api/item"
    params='{"id":"{{app.itemId}}"}'
    handle-as="json" 
    on-response="loadItem" 
    debounce-duration="1000">
</iron-ajax>
```

With this example the (wrong) generated url is:
`http://localhost:8080/api/item?id=%7B%7Bapp.childId%7D%7D`

---

The route to display the element is set up like this:

```
page("/polymer/item", function() {
    app.route = "itemform";
});

page("/polymer/item/:itemId", function(data) {
    app.route = "itemform";
    app.params = data.params;
});
```

Comment: did you try with an object in params?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550131/iron-ajax-data-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I added the logic to make the request or not, to my routing setup.

There are two different routes anyway, one without param, and one with.

I just added the `generateRequest()` call to the route WITH parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you have a fundamental issue with how you provide the itemId in the parameter.
It cannot be within the string of the 'params' attribute. The best way to resolve that is to use a function: (this assumes the itemId is a value within the "app" template)

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <iron-ajax id="itemAPI"
        url="/api/item"
        params='{{createIdParam(itemId)}}'
        handle-as="json" 
        on-response="loadItem" 
        debounce-duration="1000">
    </iron-ajax>
</template>
<script>
    app.createIdParam = function(id) { return {id:id}; }
</script>
```

The next issue is that it seems you do not want the `iron-ajax` to auto-request when the URL is set. Since the string "false" is truthy (weird, sure but true) it will make the request. Simply do not include the `auto` parameter, then use the following code (using the ajax changes my example above) to initiate the ajax request.

```
if (app.itemId)
    document.querySelector("#itemAPI").generateRequest();
```

Hope the answers more than your original question.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work in my project. I see no request made at all. Is it ok to place the call to generateRequest() simply in the <script> block of the <dom-module> of the elment ? Do I understand correct that <template is="dom-bind" id="app"> is the global <template> node and not the one inside the element ?

Comment: Correct. #app is global template block. This creates a global scope. In your question, you had asked that the request not be made if itemId was null. So, you need to, somewhere in your code, check for item ID changing, and make the call to generateRequest when you know it has a non-null value. Or, on the server side, ignore calls with null itemId. It isn't making a request because you need to manually call generateReqeust when you are ready to make the call. Also, in my code, #itemApi should be #itemAPI (case sensitivity)